# Finding circles in scatter

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, cluster-analysis, scatter-plot

I am working with a sensor and I have collected data which represented in two lists:

```
filtered_x = [64, 90, 83, 78, 57, 58....]
filtered_y = [26, 17, 63, 21, 62, 86....]
```

Which gives the following scatter plot:

[image: plot of data]

This is part of a calibration process. In order to complete this, I have to find the circles in the plot and come up with coordinates of the centers of the circles so the sensor can be calibrated. Which libraries should I use and how do I go about doing this? I have come across nearest K neighbor but I cannot find any practical approaches to applying this to both lists to identify the centers of the 25 clusters. The readings as a result of a flashing LED board.

Comment: I think a clustering algorithm, like those implemented in scikit-learn, will do what you need.  [Here's an example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_mean_shift.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-mean-shift-py).

Comment: I was thinking that `scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans` could be a way to do this, but it causes some trouble, so I asked a [question about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44660551/using-scipy-kmeans-for-cluster-analysis).

Comment: thanks for the code, however, when I run it, it works fine when I run it with x and y as my own data, `features = np.c_[x, y]` it gives `[[44 80]]` as the result for features, and `clusters = kmeans(features, 25)` throws up an error with: TypeError: type other than float or double not supported

Comment: features should be a 2D numpy array with as many rows as you have points. If this is the case, make sure that it really is a float array as the error suggests: `features = np.c_[x, y].astype(float)`

Comment: I've done that thanks, now it gives me two outputs that are completely out. It also gives the following: RuntimeWarning: Some columns have standard deviation zero. The values of these columns will not change.
  RuntimeWarning). Your code is amazing, I need to work out why my data is different to the data your generating, can I email you my data? you can contact me via my website and I can email you through there www.maxwellflitton.com

Comment: Well the kmeans relies on some statistics and I would guess when all values are identical, it will not be able to calculate distances. But it's only a warning, so it may not matter. If you have further problems you may of course update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use kernel density estimation (KDE), and find maxima.

Because that is what you want to find, the most dense locations.